# How to add custom customer attribute in customer edit account page

Tags: magento-2.1, php

I am using below code to add attribute in my custom module.

```
namespace BoostMyShop\Enhancement\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;
    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }
    /**
     * Installs DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $entityTypeId = $customerSetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY);

    $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "company_name",  array(
        "type"     => "varchar",
        "backend"  => "",
        "label"    => "Company Name",
        "input"    => "text",
        "source"   => '',
        "visible"  => true,
        "required" => true,
        "default" => "",
        "frontend" => "",
        "unique"     => false,
        "note"       => "",
        "position" => 998,
        "is_used_in_grid" => true,
        "is_visible_in_grid" => true,
        "is_filterable_in_grid" => true,
        "is_searchable_in_grid" => true

    ));
    $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "company_registration",  array(
        "type"     => "varchar",
        "backend"  => "",
        "label"    => "Company Registration",
        "input"    => "text",
        "source"   => '',
        "visible"  => true,
        "required" => true,
        "default" => "",
        "frontend" => "",
        "unique"     => false,
        "note"       => "",
        "position" => 999,
        "is_used_in_grid" => true,
        "is_visible_in_grid" => true,
        "is_filterable_in_grid" => true,
        "is_searchable_in_grid" => true

    ));

    $regulation   = $customerSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "company_name");

    $regulation = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'company_name');
    $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
    $used_in_forms[] = "adminhtml_customer";
    $regulation->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100);
    $regulation->save();

    $installer->endSetup();
}
}
```

Using above code attribute is showing in admin grid , admin customer edit page.
But I want them in Edit Account Information page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you run command php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya Yes I have run this command.
Attribute is created sucessfully. Also Showing in admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write script in edit.phtml file for that custom attribute,
So do override vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\form\edit.phtml in your module.

Comment: Thank you for reply. 
Yes I tried that. I am using below code in my edit.phtml file. But Given me error undefined index "company_name"


<?php $_company_name = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('BoostMyShop\Enhancement\Block\Widget\Companyname') ?>
<?php echo $_company_name->setCompanyname($block->getCustomer()->getCustomAttributes()['company_name'])->toHtml() ?>

Comment: Use following code instead of last line code,
From

<?php echo $_company_name->setCompanyname($block->getCustomer()->getCus‌​‌​tomAttributes()['c‌​om‌​pany_name'])->to‌​Html‌​() ?>


To


$getCustomattribute = $block->getCustomer()->getCustomAttributes();
echo $getImageValue = $getCustomattribute['com‌​pany_name']->getValue();

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: When I tried print_r($getCustomattribute['company_name'])

Its Giving me following

Comment: Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValue Object
(
    [_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [attribute_code] => company_name
            [value] => eeeeee
        )

)

Answer (score 1):

try this in phtml file:

```
<?php echo \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session')->getCustomer()->getCompanyName(); ?>
```