# How to make street field optional in M2

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I want to make street address field on checkout page optional.
For this I made change in eav_attribute table inside is_required removed 1 and added 0.
But when I click place order button, the error is :

```
{"message":"Please check the shipping address information. street is a required field."}
```

Comment: You can see my answer : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/260068/magento-2-make-address-fields-not-required-at-customer-registration/260475#260475

Comment: @AmitNaraniwal, I tried your solution, but didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using Knockout.js validation.
Remove the data-validate attribute